# La app se detiene al intentar ingresar datos a una base de datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-sqlite

soy nuevo en la programacion en android studio, intento hacer una aplicacion que maneja una base de datos de SQLite sin embargo al momento de intentar registrar datos la app se detiene.
Estos son mis codigos:
NOTA: estoy trabajando con fragments.

**XML del fragment:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".VentaFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:text="Registro:"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Nombre:"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TxtNombre"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nombre"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Telefono:"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TxtTelefono"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Telefono"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Direccion:"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TxtDireccion"
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Direccion"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Facebook:"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Txtfb"
        android:layout_width="328dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Facebook"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnRegistrar"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Registrar"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Código java del fragment:**

```
package apps.rojas.proyecto_bd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ClienteFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText etNom,etTel,etDir,etFb;
    Button btnAregis;

    public ClienteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente,container,false);

        etNom = (EditText) v.findViewById( R.id.TxtNombre );
        etTel = (EditText) v.findViewById( R.id.TxtTelefono );
        etDir= (EditText) v.findViewById( R.id.TxtDireccion );
        etFb = (EditText) v.findViewById( R.id.Txtfb );
        btnAregis = (Button) v.findViewById( R.id.BtnRegistrar );
        btnAregis.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String stretNom= etNom.getText().toString();
                String stretTel= etTel.getText().toString();
                String stretDir= etDir.getText().toString();
                String stretFb= etFb.getText().toString();

                UsuarioSQLiteHelper usuario= new UsuarioSQLiteHelper( this, "BDClientes",null,1 );
                SQLiteDatabase db= usuario.getWritableDatabase();

                db.execSQL( "INSERT INTO Cliente (nombre,telefono,direccion,facebook )VALUES("+ stretNom +","+stretTel+","+stretDir+","+stretFb+"')") ;
                db.close();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Registro Completado con Exito",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                etNom.setText( "" );
                etTel.setText( "" );
                etDir.setText( "" );
                etFb.setText( "" );
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
>
Codigo java de la Base de Datos:
>package apps.rojas.proyecto_bd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;

public class UsuarioSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sql= "CREATE TABLE Cliente(nombre,TEXT,telefono,TEXT,direccion,TEXT,facebook,TEXT,debe,TEXT,pago,TEXT,fecha,TEXT)";
    public UsuarioSQLiteHelper(View.OnClickListener context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super( (Context) context, name, factory, version );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     db.execSQL( sql );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cliente" );
        db.execSQL( sql );
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. El error está en el "BtnRegistrar" al momento de darle clic la app se cierra.

De antemano, ¡¡GRACIAS!!

Comment: Podrías añadir el Logcat para ver que error te está dando ?

Comment: Si no usas el LogCat para determinar cual es el problema, las causas pueden ser... "infinitas"...

Answer (score 1):

El problema que se presenta al dar click es que estas usando como contexto `this`, si estas en un `Fragment`, recuerda utilizar el contexto de la `Activity` que carga el `Fragment` , usa `getActivity()` :

```
UsuarioSQLiteHelper usuario = new UsuarioSQLiteHelper(getActivity(), "BDClientes",null,1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes agregar el Logcat seria de gran ayuda para identificar el problema. Aún así voy a corregir alguna cosa que veo que están mal.

1º
En `UsuarioSQLiteHelper` cuando creas la tabla, estas usando:

```
String sql= "CREATE TABLE Cliente(nombre,TEXT,telefono,TEXT,direccion,TEXT,facebook,TEXT,debe,TEXT,pago,TEXT,fecha,TEXT)";
```

Eso debería darte error ya que estas repitiendo la tabla `TEXT`, modificalo de esta manera:

```
String sql= "CREATE TABLE if not exists Cliente(nombre,telefono,direccion,facebook,debe,pago,fecha)";
```

2º
En tu `Fragment` el constructor de la `SQL` esta a falta de `'` (comillas), teniéndolo de ésta manera:

```
db.execSQL( "INSERT INTO Cliente (nombre,telefono,direccion,facebook )VALUES("+ stretNom +","+stretTel+","+stretDir+","+stretFb+"')") ;
```

Modificalo de la siguiente forma para que no te de error ahi:

```
db.execSQL( "INSERT INTO Cliente (nombre,telefono,direccion,facebook )VALUES('"+ stretNom +"','"+stretTel+"','"+stretDir+"','"+stretFb+"')") ;
```

3º
La clase `SQLiteOpenHelper` como primer argumento necesita el contexto, en tu clase, tienes de la siguiente manera:

```
public UsuarioSQLiteHelper(View.OnClickListener context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super( (Context) context, name, factory, version );
}
```

Estas casteando un `ClickListener` a `Context`. agrega directamente el contexto de la aplicación de la siguiente manera:

```
public UsuarioSQLiteHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super( context, name, factory, version );
}
```

Y al haber modificado ahi, en tu `Fragment` modifica el **this** por **getActivity()**:

```
UsuarioSQLiteHelper usuario= new UsuarioSQLiteHelper( getActivity(), "BDClientes",null,1 );
```